# Using the datetime module with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to implement the current time in a chatbox. I searched around here, but can't really figure out what is wrong with my code. Thanks to everyone reading or helping me out!

```js
let dt = new Date();
$('#datetime').html = dt.toLocaleTimeString();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="content">     
  <p>Date/Time: <span id="datetime"></span></p>       
</textarea>
```

Comment: you can't put html to textarea and act on it like this, hard to tell what you want to achieve and what you mean by "implement the current time in a chatbox"; generally you need to preformat it as a string and then add it to the textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this. You can simply use [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) jQuery function. At current you are not using `html` function correctly.

You can simply add `datetime` directly into the `textarea`.

To show `time` you are already using  `toLocaleTimeString` - To show the date you can use `toDateString()` to show current date.

Run snippet below.

```js
let dt = new Date();
$('#content').html('Date/Time: '+dt.toDateString()+' ' +dt.toLocaleTimeString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="content">     
    
</textarea>
```